# Reducing spacing between lines when using atop

Tags: r

I have been using `atop` and `expression` in R to create axis labels for some figures, as I need to italicise some words, use superscripts and my labels need to be over two lines.

This is an example of what I'm using:

```
plot(c(1:10),ylab="")
mtext(side=2,line=2,expression(atop('Mean height of ', italic(Dicksonia~antarctica)*  ' (m)')))
```

[image]

However, the space between the two lines is too big for my figures. Can I reduce this space?

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you skip the `atop` part and stick with the standard `\n` to indicate a new line. In this case, you can control the spacing by the graphic parameter `lheight` in `par`. So, you can do something like this:

```
par(lheight=.5) # or adjust to whatever
plot(c(1:10),ylab="")
mtext(side=2,line=2,expression('Mean height of \n', italic(Dicksonia~antarctica)*  ' (m)'))
```

It could also possibly work with `atop` by I couldn't figure it out! So any comments (or other answers) about that would be welcome!

Comment: Great, at least that solves my problem. I didn't realise \n could work with expressions, I must have been trying it wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

There is a solution with using `atop()` only, as you were exploring first time, but is a bit more verbose than the solution with just using `\n` as posted by Yannis [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50126864/5193830).

The main idea is that every time we call `atop()` within another `atop()`, the text gets smaller, but also the gap between the lines, so we can use that in our advantage. For your two lines example, we could call `atop()` two times, one within another, which forces 3 lines, but we set the first line empty (`NA` or `NULL` or `""` will work), so that the next `atop()` plots a smaller gap between the lines, but also the text gets smaller. To solve the problem of the text getting smaller, we must employ `textstyle()`. Well, things get easily verbose, but is nevertheless a solution.

---

The original code from the question, illustrating the issue with the wide gap between the two lines of text; on my device is even pushing the first line outside of the "canvas" (I plot it here for comparison reasons, so to see clearly what the proposed solution does):

```r
plot(c(1:10),ylab="")
mtext(side=2,line=2,expression(atop('Mean height of ', italic(Dicksonia~antarctica)*  ' (m)')))
```

[image]

Reduce the gap between the two lines of text with two `atop()` calls and the `textstyle()` wraps. I also took the liberty to replac the `*  ' (m)'` with `~ (m)`, mostly to show that that is possible as well, giving a slightly different visual aspect of the brackets:

```r
plot(c(1:10), ylab = "")
mtext(side = 2, line = 2, 
      expression(atop(NA, atop(textstyle('Mean height of'),
                               textstyle(italic(Dicksonia ~ antarctica) ~ (m))))))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-01-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Commenting here to say this solution worked best for me with multiple lines within a legend; \n was causing some really weird line spacing and justification. Verbose, but it worked best for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `lheight` parameter in `par()` function and slightly modify your `expression()` input:

```
par(lheight=0.2)   # the default is 1
plot(c(1:10),ylab="")

# Use new line character to separate the lines and 
# apply atop() command to the second part of your expression:
mtext(side=2,line=2,
      expression('Mean height of \n', atop(italic(Dicksonia~antarctica)*  ' (m)')))
```

Comment: Great, that works. Although I don't think I need the atop if I use \n. Thanks